# about UIView addSubview

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

I have two UIViews, named A and B, and I add UIView B into A's subviews:

```
[A.view addSubview B]
```

I am wondering is there any delegation or hook that B can be informed "Oh, I was added into A!" when it was added to A? or any other way to let B know it was added to some other UIView container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `willMoveToSuperview:` or `didMoveToSuperview` methods in a `UIView` subclass in order to be informed when the view is added to another view.